# flexbox not adjusting div width to its width in css

Tags: layout, flexbox, tags, overflow, width

hello i am creating my web where i am creating a header of full width and down there a container which has height of - headers width,
there were 3 div in container => sidebar, main
the problem is when i was creating a div name tags in main takes 100% width of container of flex

like sidebar have 300px width so main has 100% width so it will auto adjust but whe i set tags 100% it takes 100% of container and overflowing even after giving overflow-x scroll

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>page layout</title>

    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            background: #fcfcfc;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .wrapper header {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            padding: 7px 12px;
            background: #fff;
        }

        .wrapper .layout {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        .layout .sidebar {
            width: 250px;
            background: #fff;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .layout .main {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .main .tags {
            display: flex;
            padding: 7px 12px;
            list-style: none;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }

        .tags li{
            white-space: none;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 30px;
            margin-right: 12px;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            padding: 2px 22px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>header</header>
        <div class="layout">
            <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
            <div class="main">
                <ul class="tags">
                    <li class="tag-item">science video</li>
                    <li class="tag-item">experiment video</li>
                    <li class="tag-item">coding lecture video</li>
                    <li class="tag-item">css tricks and tutorial video</li>
                    <li class="tag-item">gaming videos video</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```